# How to port my own device driver on android emulator

Tags: android, driver, port

Can anyone tell me how can i install or port my own driver(EX: Display driver) on android emulator and how to test it....

Thanks, Manju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have read the [Display Drivers](http://source.android.com/porting/display_drivers.html) section of the porting documention as well as bits about the [Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) (AVD) emulator configuration already.  An AVD device can be configured to match your characteristics of your display, but that won't actually test your display driver.   It doesn't appear that the emulator is extensible in that regard (without modifying QEMU).

So .. perhaps write an application-level test suite that runs on the emulator, and then try it on your actual device.